# Is there a canonical book on Android Development?

Tags: books, android

I am getting into Android Development and want a book to help fill in some of the gaps.

Is there a book out there that's the de-facto standard for describing best practices, design methodologies, and other helpful information on Android Development? What about that book makes it special?

Comment: What is your level of experience in other programming languages? That often plays a huge part in choosing a good programming book for a given language or platform.

Comment: I don't think you need a book for that, the official documentation is just great, and there are tons of tutorials floating around the internet already that cover most if not everything you can do with Android.

Comment: @MahmoudHossam There is a difference between data and information.  In this case, it's helpful to have something that walks thru the process, helping show the basics.  The official documentation is mostly a data dump that assumes some expertise to use.

Comment: @Paul maybe the API reference is a data dump, but not the dev guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Professional Android 2 Application Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470565527) is the book that I used to learn Android. The first 4 chapters provide a general overview of the development environment and the basic features every program contains. From there, pick and choose chapters based on your project idea.

Comment: Some of its examples don't work. And the author still hasn't provided corrections on the accompanying forum.

Comment: I think I will buy this book.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk : That means there is a challenge there to find and fix the errors. Well, if the errors are primarily in the examples, that is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're familiar with Java, I highly suggest checking out ["Beginning Android 3" By Mark Murphy](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=beginning%20android&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&resnum=4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=643&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=4081897737388412543&sa=X&ei=pZvmTr7CB8SY2AXPn63hCA&ved=0CG0Q8wIwAA)

I'm a beginner myself, and this book has helped immensely.

Comment: I am also still new to java.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you pick up [Java: An Introduction to Problem Solving & Programming By Walter Savitch](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=java+an+introduction+to+problem+solving&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=10698386736938515118&sa=X&ei=BAPpTuKjA8b7sQLA5d2XCQ&ved=0CFMQ8wIwBA). We used the 5th edition in my Java class and it helped me immensely.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much information out there, the best way to start probably isn't by reading a book. In my opinion the best way to start is to go to the [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com).  They explain how to do virtually everything.  Look through the sample projects and make sure you can get them up and running.  Once you have done this and have a higher level understanding of Android and java, then it might be time to look at a book such as [The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/) depending on what you are looking to do with Android.

Comment: @z, I learn best when I have a book I can sit down with. I suppose I am not disciplined enough to stay focused when I am on the internet. :)

Comment: The Android Developer Site is like drinking from a fire hose

Answer (score 0):

To me, definitively paying for a suscription in [Commonsware](http://commonsware.com/Android/) was the best resource related to development of Android apps. Also Mark Murphy gives you weekly office hours and all the source code is in his [Github account](https://github.com/commonsguy).